# 403 forbidden error when IIS is binding ASP web app on port 8080 to be accessed via a subdirectory

Tags: webserver, iis, localhost, asp

Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5

I have a number of folders in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`;

```
 - wwwroot
  - index.html
  - analytics (PHP app)
  - occupancy (PHP app)
  - rooms (ASP app)
```

In IIS my sites structure is;

```
 - Default Web Site (bindings config is http port 80 / https port 443)
  - analytics (application)
  - occupancy (application)
  - rooms (application)
 - Room Booking (bindings config is http port 8080)
  - files
```

In my Default Web Site I have created an application for each site. I am able to access `localhost/analytics` and `localhost/occupancy` without issue, but when I try to access `localhost/rooms` I get the following error;

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
> the contents of this directory. Most likely causes: A default document
> is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not
> enabled on the server.

However if I visit `http://localhost:8080` I can see the application successfully.

So, how can I access the `rooms` application via `localhost/rooms`

I've made no other changes to system files. Little to no experience with IIS here.

Comment: Doesn't IIS require a default.aspx page even for applications?  It's been several years since I worked with IIS, but as I recall, a default.aspx page called the actual application.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your configuration for the PHP applications and ASP application?  A screenshot of the configuration would be enough for somebody to see what is going on and help you.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above.  IIS assumes that if you don't provide a default page, that you are attempting to browse the directory's contents-hence the error message.  With a basic html site, you would have default.html, or index.html.  With .NET, I always used a default.aspx page that loaded the code for the application.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working by creating a new `rooms` application pool.

Then in `default websites > rooms > basic settings` I changed the `application pool` to the newly created `rooms`.

I still don't know why this worked but it has. Hope it helps someone else.